# GLUT Key Mapping Duplicates

Tags: opengl, switch-statement, glut, 2d-games, keymapping

I am currently working on a game that uses the arrow keys to control sprite movement.  I am trying to add a second player that uses the wasd keys to move, but the GLUT_KEY_LEFT is defined as 100, which interferes with the 'd' key in my switch statement ('d' has an ascii value of 100).  Is there any way to change the value of GLUT_KEY_LEFT or any other workaround that would allow me to use both the left arrow key and the 'd' key simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

The arrow keys are reported through the GLUT special key callback (registered with `glutSpecialFunc`). Character keys come in through the regular keyboard callback (registered with `glutKeyboardFunc`). That's how you keep them apart.